# searching for an array in a schema by id

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
const FormFieldsSchema = new Schema({
  formName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  fields: [
    {
      fieldLabel: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      inputData: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "UserData"
      }]
    }
  ]
});
```

Hi guys, I have a schema in which fields is an array, now for every array item I have an _id property, I wish to find that array and update it, but I can't manage to do it,
I tried `findByIdAndUpdate`, but it didnt work, also tried `parent.inputData.id(_id);` no luck yet, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the content of your array into a separate model, then you can query the model directly.

running `findByIdAndUpdate` on `FormFieldsSchema` fill search for the `_id` of `FormFields` not the content of `fields` array.

```
const FieldSchema = new Schema({
      fieldLabel: {
          type: String,
          required: true
      },
      inputData: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "UserData"
      }]
})
```

and change `field` into `fields: [FieldSchema]`
also, don't forget to export `FieldSchema` as a model.